# in dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event doesnt change its state

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

In the following code everytime its taking only one item from dropdownlist. When I select any other item from dropdownlist its same as first item.

Please give solution

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet _subcat = new DataSet();
    _subcat = serviceus.Get_SERVICEUS_SUB_CATEGORYLIST(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    lbsubcategory.DataSource = _subcat.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    lbsubcategory.DataTextField = Convert.ToString(_subcat.Tables[0].Columns["CATEGORY_SUB1_NAME"].ColumnName);
    lbsubcategory.DataBind();
    Label5.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. To do this, edit your post, select the code, then press Ctrl-K or choose the 'Code Sample' button from the toolbar above the edit box.

Answer (score 1):

Check how you bind your dropdownlist. I think you're binding it everytime your page posts back to server. Try to use IsPostBack property of the page :

```
if (!IsPostBack){
   DropDownList1.DataSource = datasource;
   DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have:

```
if(!IsPostBack) {
    DataBind();
}
```

around your initial databind (eg in OnLoad)

Answer (score 0):

EnableViewState="False" on the lbsubcategory.

Assuming AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"